# istio service registry with ui

Tags: deployment, istio, istio-kiali

I have stumble upon register/deploy new service in istio with user interface (not by command line) but i didnt find any mean to do that, even i read all kiali source to get any clue on how that communicate with istio/k8s go clients.is it even possible to add new service in mesh by using an user interface to support both istio and service registry?
Also Does go client support the service registry feature for istio or k8s??

apparently kiali does not support such feature... but i hope at least  go client have such option.